# ActiveX Controls not working on Edge IE Mode

Tags: microsoft-edge, activex

My ASP.Net application with activeX controls doesn't work on Edge Browser, I have already set IE mode on edge. Application works  fine with Internet Explorer 11 on the same PC.

Can any one help in this issue